Out of memory while compiling a simple pgfplots that reads a csv file
I have a csv file that stores pixel values of a 320x160 image. I'm trying to use tikz to create the figure in pdf but compilation fails with an exceed memory error. I don't want to try increase memory because I've done that only once and I don't think I can push that further. Instead, I want to understand what's the issue with this code that's taking up so much memory:
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\newcommand\n{320}
\newcommand\m{160}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{design.csv}\data
        
        \foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,\n}{
            \foreach \y[count=\yi from 0] in {1,...,\m}{
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,-\y)}]
                    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\yi}{\xi}\of{\data}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaled}{\pgfplotsretval*100}
                    \draw[draw=none,fill=black!\scaled] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
                \end{scope}
            }
        }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The csv file can be found here.
UPDATE
I changed the code and removed the scope but it still doesn't work. This is the new code:
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand\n{160}
\newcommand\m{80}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{design_cnn_mbb_4.csv}\CNNbending
  
  \foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,\n}{
    \foreach \y[count=\yi from 0] in {1,...,\m}{    
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\yi}{\xi}\of{\CNNbending}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaled}{\pgfplotsretval*100}
        \draw[draw=none,fill=black!\scaled] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+1,\y+1);
    }
  }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

UPDATE 2
I tried using another way, this time using the built-in pgfplots functionality of addplot while reading a table in csv format:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis line style={draw=none},
    axis equal image,
    ticks=none,
    colormap/blackwhite,
    colormap={reverse blackwhite}{
        indices of colormap={
            \pgfplotscolormaplastindexof{blackwhite},...,0 of blackwhite}
    },
  point meta min=0,
  point meta max=1,
]
% Assuming you still want to use the same data file
\addplot+ [only marks, scatter, mark=square*, mark size=1.1, mark options={solid}, point meta={\thisrow{value}}, line width=0pt] table [x index=0,y index=1, z index=3, col sep=comma] {./design_xyz.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This still doesn't work as I get the same out of memory error. The file I used can be found here.

Does this answer your question? How to expand TeX's "main memory size"? (pgfplots memory overload)

Maybe you can skip some values from the CSV file, as they may not be visible to the naked eye.

You can always use some external tool to generate the image and then import it. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414219/rendering-a-csv-with-pixel-values-to-an-image-with-pyplot

a "simple" pgfplots?? You are producing over 50000 pictures in shifted scopes in a nested loop. Even if you remove all the pgfplots stuff this will be exceed memory.

@codeR I stated explicitly I don’t want to increase the memory because I’ve done that in the past.

@UlrikeFischer is it the shifted scope the issue with the memory?

Certainly ... you're not moving pixels, but objects in the C++ sense.

Assuming, things work: What is your image going to show? A kind of heat map? Some correlation valey? // As stated pgfplots might be an alternative, provided it can handle the amount of data. But also package graphicx can be your friend to include pdf (!) drawings, i.e. vector drawings or images, depending on your external tool.

@MS-SPO I'm using pgfplots to create vector images. How can graphicx be of help there?

See its manual, and find some examples here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A245790+graphicx+standalone
